# Apache Flink: Custom InputFormat only runs with parallelism of 1

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-flink

I am implementing a custom input format for Apache Flink. I have created a dummy input format which returns 3 rows.

```
public class ElasticsearchInputFormat extends GenericInputFormat<Row> {
    @Override
    public void configure(Configuration parameters) {
        System.out.println("configuring");
    }

    @Override
    public BaseStatistics getStatistics(BaseStatistics cachedStatistics) throws IOException {
        return cachedStatistics;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(GenericInputSplit split) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("opening: " + split);
        super.open(split);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("closing");
        super.close();
    }

    private int a = 0;

    public boolean reachedEnd() throws IOException {
        a++;
        return a > 3;
    }

    public Row nextRecord(Row reuse) throws IOException {
        Row r = new Row(2);
        r.setField(0, "osman");
        r.setField(1, "wow");
        return r;
    }
}
```

And my sample code is as follows:

```
final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.createCollectionsEnvironment();
env.setParallelism(8);

DataSource<Row> input = env.createInput(new ElasticsearchInputFormat());

input.print();
```

However, although the parallelism is set to 8, it prints:

```
configuring
opening: GenericSplit (0/1)
closing
osman,wow
osman,wow
osman,wow
```

Why is it not parallelized? I want to have multiple splits, so it can be consumed in parallel by other operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createCollectionsEnvironment()` returns a special environment that has an implicit parallelism of 1. From the Javadocs...

> Creates a {@link CollectionEnvironment} that uses Java Collections
>   underneath. This will execute in a single thread in the current
>   JVM. It is very fast but will fail if the data does not fit into
>   memory. parallelism will always be 1. This is useful during
>   implementation and for debugging.

Comment: Ow, that's my bad, just a copy paste from another example, regular `createEnvironment` works just fine with the desired parallelism. Much appreciated.